# Is it possible to sync an outlook.com account with an IMAP server?

Tags: imap, email

I'm searching for a way to sync one or more outlook.com accounts with an internal IMAP server.

Gmail and other popular services offers IMAP, so it's pretty easy to do with imapsync ( http://imapsync.lamiral.info/ ).

But with Outlook, it doesn't look like it's possible.

I know that i can access it using POP3 but in this case Junk, Sent and other folders won't be synced.

Any ideas of what i can do?

Comment: I'm lost as to the why...I can understand an IMAP client, but why would an internal IMAP server need to sync?  Just hoping to help after understanding what you are wanting to accomplish in full.

Answer (score 2):

This is really ***NOT*** the way you're supposed to be using outlook.com ; that said, your options are extremely limited here.

1. [Do like TomTom said](https://serverfault.com/a/494611/32986) and invest some development time in writing a connector.
   (I believe MAPI is supported, but check with Microsoft on this because I may be wrong.)
2. Switch to a provider that supports IMAP, which makes the sync MUCH easier.
3. Use outlook.com the way it's intended to be used
   (i.e. "Stop trying to sync it to a local server, mail proxies are bad.")
4. Run your own mail server connected to the public internet.

Comment: All things being equal you should really go with option #3 or #4.